# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels. How to solve?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Since I'm new to the field, I'm posing this question, although there are already some partial answers. I don't know the concrete solution to my problem.
I'm trying to install dependencies for executing a code sent by my university supervisor by executing

`conda install --yes --file requirements.txt`

Then I get the following error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - click-default-group==1.2.2
  - profiling==0.1.3
  - jupyter-console==6.1.0
  - mypy-extensions==0.4.3
  - tables==3.6.1
  - numpy==1.18.3
  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - jupyter-core==4.6.3
  - prometheus-client==0.7.1
  - torch==1.4.0
  - torchvision==0.5.0
  - opencv-python==4.2.0.34
  - jupyter-client==6.1.2
  - valuedispatch==0.0.1
  - nbformat==5.0.5

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
```

There was a solution suggested by using an YAML-file instead of the .txt, but I'm not quite sure how to implement this.

Best

Edit:
The content of the requirements.txt is (although quite long):

```
appdirs==1.4.4
astroid==2.3.3
attrs==19.3.0
autopep8==1.5.2
backcall==0.1.0
black==19.10b0
bleach==3.1.4
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
click-default-group==1.2.2
ConfigArgParse==1.2.3
configparser==5.0.0
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.17
decorator==4.4.2
deepdish==0.3.6
defusedxml==0.6.0
entrypoints==0.3
faiss-cpu==1.6.3
faiss-gpu==1.6.3
h5py==2.10.0
hdbscan==0.8.26
idna==2.9
ipykernel==5.2.0
ipython==7.13.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
isort==4.3.21
jedi==0.16.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
joblib==0.14.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.2
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3
kiwisolver==1.2.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
llvmlite==0.31.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mypy==0.770
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.5
notebook==6.0.3
numba==0.48.0
numexpr==2.7.1
numpy==1.18.3
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
pandas==1.0.3
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.6.2
pathspec==0.8.0
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==7.1.1
profiling==0.1.3
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.5
protobuf==3.11.3
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pycodestyle==2.5.0
Pygments==2.6.1
pylint==2.4.4
pyparsing==2.4.6
pyrsistent==0.16.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==19.0.0
qtconsole==4.7.2
QtPy==1.9.0
regex==2020.5.7
requests==2.23.0
scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.10.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.14.0
tables==3.6.1
tensorboardX==2.0
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
toml==0.10.0
torch==1.4.0
torchvision==0.5.0
tornado==6.0.4
tqdm==4.45.0
traitlets==4.3.3
typed-ast==1.4.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2
umap-learn==0.3.10
urllib3==1.25.8
urwid==2.1.0
valuedispatch==0.0.1
wcwidth==0.1.9
webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the text file please?

Comment: Pip requirement files are not immediately compatible with Conda environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some of the subversions of the packages in the requirements file were built for PyPi distribution, but not conda.  Also, some of the package names for PyPi use dashes, but they use underscores on conda.

This can be fixed by loosening the subversion in the requirements files and replacing some of the dashes with underscores.

Some of the packages have different names as well.  For instance Torch is called pytorch.  Also, the you will need to include the pytorch channel.

Lastly, the `valuedispatch` package is only on PyPi, and will have to installed using PIP.

Replace the requirements file with the on below, and then run the following commands:

```
conda install -y --file requirements.txt -c defaults -c conda-forge -c pytorch
pip install valuedispatch
pip install profiling
```

requirements.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.*
astroid==2.3.*
attrs==19.3.*
autopep8==1.5.*
backcall==0.1.*
black==19.*
bleach==3.1.*
certifi==2019.11.*
chardet==3.0.*
click==7.1.*
click-default-group==1.2.*
ConfigArgParse==1.2.*
configparser==5.0.*
cycler==0.10.*
Cython==0.29.*
decorator==4.4.*
deepdish==0.3.*
defusedxml==0.6.*
entrypoints==0.*
faiss-cpu==1.6.*
faiss-gpu==1.6.*
h5py==2.10.*
hdbscan==0.8.*
idna==2.*
ipykernel==5.2.*
ipython==7.13.*
ipython_genutils==0.2.*
ipywidgets==7.5.*
isort==4.3.*
jedi==0.16.*
Jinja2==2.11.*
joblib==0.14.*
jsonschema==3.2.*
jupyter==1.0.*
jupyter_client==6.1.*
jupyter_console==6.1.*
jupyter_core==4.6.*
kiwisolver==1.2.*
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.*
llvmlite==0.31.*
MarkupSafe==1.1.*
matplotlib==3.2.*
mccabe==0.6.*
mistune==0.8.*
mypy==0.*
mypy_extensions==0.4.*
nbconvert==5.6.*
nbformat==5.0.*
notebook==6.0.*
numba==0.48.*
numexpr==2.7.*
numpy==1.18.*
opencv==4.2.*
pandas==1.0.*
pandocfilters==1.4.*
parso==0.6.*
pathspec==0.8.*
pexpect==4.8.*
pickleshare==0.7.*
Pillow==7.1.*
prometheus_client==0.7.*
prompt_toolkit==3.0.*
protobuf==3.11.*
ptyprocess==0.6.*
pycodestyle==2.5.*
Pygments==2.6.*
pylint==2.4.*
pyparsing==2.4.*
pyrsistent==0.16.*
python-dateutil==2.8.*
pytz==2019.*
PyYAML==5.3.*
pyzmq==19.0.*
qtconsole==4.7.*
QtPy==1.9.*
regex==2020.5.*
requests==2.23.*
scikit-learn==0.22.*
scipy==1.4.*
seaborn==0.10.*
Send2Trash==1.5.*
six==1.14.*
pytables==3.6.*
tensorboardX==2.*
terminado==0.8.*
testpath==0.4.*
toml==0.10.*
pytorch==1.4.*
torchvision==0.5.*
tornado==6.0.*
tqdm==4.45.*
traitlets==4.3.*
typed-ast==1.4.*
typing-extensions==3.7.*
umap-learn==0.3.*
urllib3==1.25.*
urwid==2.1.*
wcwidth==0.1.*
webencodings==0.5.*
widgetsnbextension==3.5.*
wrapt==1.11.*
```

Alternatively, you could probably install everything using PIP and the original file via:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But as @merv mentioned, it is best to not do this in the base environment.

Comment: Works perfectly, except for two packages. Namely, 

  - profiling=0.1
  - tables=3.6.

Comment: Tables became pytables, profiling is also only on PyPi.  I updated the answer.

Comment: I'd note that one should not `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the **base** environment.